# How to reboot android phone from kernel code

Tags: android

Is it possible to reboot by calling `SYSCALL(sys_reboot,sys_reboot,sys32_reboot_wrapper)`?

Comment: Normally no. Is you phone rooted?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can only if your mobile device is rooted. As alternative you can run adb reboot within your code. adb has the super user permission.

Comment: That is wrong. adb has no su permission if you run `adb sh id` you won't get the output root. But I think you are right that it is possible through the adb interface to restart the phone.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, what i meant is that him can execute adb reboot in order to restart his phone

Comment: //include this file in kernel code
#include<cutils/android_reboot.h>

//call this function
android_reboot(ANDROID_RB_RESTART,0,0);

Comment: Nope. If I enter `adb shell restart` I'll get this output: `restart: permission denied`

Comment: @Munipratap I don't think that the permission to execute will be granted.

Answer (score 1):

//include this file in kernel code

```
#include<cutils/android_reboot.h>
```

//call this function

```
android_reboot(ANDROID_RB_RESTART,0,0);
```